# String Validation With If-else functions

Tags: c#, validation, user-input

I have a question about validating user inputs that are strings.

I have a string variable set and have the `readLine()`, but when running:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Start by typing 'hello'");

        String activity = Console.ReadLine();

        if ("hello".Equals(activity))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
            WakeUp();
        }
```

I changed some of the words but it puts out the example I'm trying to use.

Regardless of what the user enters it always returns the `else{}` statement.

Is there something I am missing? A better method to get and validate user input?

Sorry for any confusion. If this isn't quite enough info I can edit and post my exact code.

So without creating a new post, how would I write that into a switch statement?

```
switch (activity){
case "hello": console.WriteLine("HI!");
   break;
case "bye": Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
   break;
default: Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
```

Comment: show your actual code

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what the value is of `variable` at the time of the `if` statement?

Comment: Your sample worked fine for me.

Comment: @jac That's weird. I don't know what I changed but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this sample help find an issue somewhere with yours?

```
Console.WriteLine("type 'q' to quit");

while (true)
{
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (input == "q")
  {
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You entered '{0}'", input);
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize if this a newbie question, but what is the {0} mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample worked fine for me. When comparing strings, it might be useful - depending on your intention - to lower the casing and trim out the whitespaces. (" hello" is not equals to "hellO")

```
Console.WriteLine("Start by typing 'hello'");
String activity = Console.ReadLine();

activity = activity.Trim().ToLower(); // try adding this line

if ("hello".Equals(activity))
    Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
    WakeUp();
}
```